# How to detect current terminal encoding and convert user input to and from utf8?

Tags: windows, go, utf-8, character-encoding, cross-platform

I am writing a golang command line program that accepts user input. This input string has to be converted to UTF-8 and sent to another server for processing. On Linux, the terminal encoding is almost always UTF-8 but this does not seem to be the case in Windows. I tried setting the codepage on windows to 65001 using

```
chcp 65001
```

and also ensured the terminal font is set to Lucida console. However, the bytes read by

```
fmt.Scanf()
```

is not in UTF-8 format. I want to be able to detect the character encoding and convert the strings to UTF-8. Similarly, I should be able to convert from UTF-8 to the local encoding before printing to the screen.

Python seems to have "locale" package which can get the default encoding, decode and encode strings to any specified encoding. Is there an equivalent of this for golang?

Most of the stackoverflow discussions pointed at using chcp 65001 to change the encoding on windows terminal to UTF-8. This doesn't seem to work for me.

```
func main() {
    foo := ""
    fmt.Printf("Enter: ")
    if _, err := fmt.Scanln(&foo) ; err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error while scanning: ", err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("Scanned bytes: % x", foo)
    fmt.Println()
}
```

On Linux:

```
// ASCII
$ go run test.go
Enter: hello
Scanned bytes: 68 65 6c 6c 6f

// Unicode
$ go run test.go
Enter: ©
Scanned bytes: c2 a9

// Unicode
$ go run test.go
Enter: ΆΏΑΓΔΘΞ
Scanned bytes: ce 86 ce 8f ce 91 ce 93 ce 94 ce 98 ce 9e ce a3 ce a8 ce a9 ce aa ce ad ce b1 ce b2 ce ba
```

On Windows:

```
PS C:\> chcp
Active code page: 437

PS C:\> go run .\test.go
Enter: hello
Scanned bytes: 68 65 6c 6c 6f

PS C:\> go run .\test.go
Enter: ΆΏΑΓΔΘΞ
Scanned bytes: 3f 3f 61

// Change to Unicode
PS C:\> chcp 65001
Active code page: 65001
PS C:\> go run .\test.go
Enter: ΆΏΑΓΔΘΞ
Error while scanning:  EOF
Scanned bytes:
```

Appreciate any help/pointers.

Comment: I don't think there is a standard way for terminal environment to expose the encoding (since you included Windows). The best solution I can think of is to manually add environment variable for this, then you read the variable with `os.Getenv()`.

Comment: Thanks, @KoalaYeung. Do you know how is unicode handled in golang in Windows environment, in general? The Scanf/bufio.read don't seem to read non-UTF-8 input.

Comment: Sorry. I have no experience in Windows with Golang. I read some article says you can do `chcp 65001` to change the code page to UTF-8. Do you think this helps?

Comment: Apparently it did not. I mentioned that in the question.

Comment: Sorry. Missed that part.

Comment: Have you tried `fmt.Fscanf` with [iconv](https://github.com/qiniu/iconv)'s `Reader`? You'd need to know before hand what the encoding is (maybe with environment variables).

Comment: @KoalaYeung Yes I tried iconv but again I need to first determine the terminal encoding. For now, I plan to use `nl_langinfo(CODESET)`  with some C code in the go program.

Answer (score -1):

I run this code in window and check it in terminal with git bash and poweshell and etc. and it's work correctly.

maybe your problem for your system language setting.

for more information about utf8 i recommend you read this package [document](https://pkg.go.dev/unicode/utf8)